# How to inflate options menu from ponTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) in View

Tags: android

I have my menu which is called by clicking the button on android tablet. But I need to inflate the same menu by a click on view.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: "But I need to inflate the same menu by a click on view." -- please do not do this. Please leave the options menu alone, so that it is accessed via the MENU button (or the icon in the action bar on Honeycomb). Please find a more appropriate UX model for whatever it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called

```
mainActivity.openOptionsMenu();
```

from View. It worked!. the one Phil suggested creates a different menu. Not an option menu.
any way thankx

Comment: Incredible. I've been looking for this for another reason, this works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use something like:

```
View myView = findViewById(R.id.my_view);
registerForContextMenu(myView);
```

in `onCreate(...)`. Now when this `View` is clicked, it will open the context menu, and you can handle it in `onCreateContextMenu(...)`. To be certain that this context menu has the same options as the main menu, you can inflate the same menu with the following code (though it will *look* like a Context Menu, not like the regular menu):

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
}
```